# Не воспроизводится аудио файл discord.py python

Tags: python, discord.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

class music(commands.Cog):
def **init**(self, bot):
self.bot = bot
print('Модуль {} загружен'.format(self.**class**.**name**))

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, file_name: str):
    voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not voice_channel:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале!")
        return

    vc = await voice_channel.connect()

    audio_file = f'audio_files/{file_name}.mp3'
    if not os.path.isfile(audio_file):
        await ctx.send( f"Файл {file_name}.mp3 не найден." )
        return

    source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_file)
    vc.play(source)
```

def setup(bot):
bot.add_cog(music(bot))

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\bot_my\cogs\music.py", line 17, in play
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1274, in connect
    raise ClientException('Already connected to a voice channel.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, *, file_name: str):
    voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    channel = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_channel:
        await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале!")
        return

    await voice_channel.connect()

    audio_file = f'audio_files/{file_name}.mp3'
    if not os.path.isfile(audio_file):
        await ctx.send( f"Файл {file_name}.mp3 не найден." )
        return

    source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_file)
    channel.play(source)
```

Comment: не работает Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\bot_my\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.